# Can jQuery read cookies?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, cookies

Simple example: I want to have some items on a page (like divs or table rows), and I want to let the user click on them to select them. That seems easy enough in jQuery. To save which items a user clicks on with no server-side post backs, I was thinking a cookie would be a simple way to get this done.

Is this assumption that a cookie is OK in this case, correct?
If it is correct, does the jQuery API have some way to read/write cookie information that is nicer than the default JavaScript APIs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a cookie plugin for jquery https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Answer (score 4):

If you are developing a web-application that is targeted to W3C-compliant browsers (or HTML5-compliant, to be precise), then you are always welcome to use **WebStorage**. Its interface is pretty straight forward and its usage in your case is a nice alternative to cookies.

You can choose between `localStorage` (permanent) and `sessionStorage` (temporary). They are both properties of the `Window` object.

Example:

```
localStorage.setItem('clicked', 'elementID'); // stores some data
localStorage.getItem('clicked'); // returns corresponding data
```

Basically, you map one string to another in a key-value manner. E.g., value might be formatted as JSON string representing an array of IDs of clicked elements.

To make sure that your user data storing functionality works "everywhere", check out the [Modernizr library](http://modernizr.com/). It has stubs implemented for missing properties: in case of `localStorage` (or `sessionStorage`) it falls back to using cookies.